# Side commentary (on every page) in two-sided book class separated with a vertical rule

Tags: multicolumn, double-sided, marginpar, marginnote

I would like to write a book and have main text with a side commentary separated with a vertical rule on every page. Side commentary should be on outer side of a page (two-sided). I am not sure if I ought to make marginal notes or columns or something else. Side commentary may, from time to time, contain pictures or tikZ 'code'. Can you please help me find the best way to achieve this? More or less I want to achieve something similar to this book:

[image]

I tried: multicols, sidenotes, framed, background, paracols, marginnotes, marginpar, but either I miss something or none of them can achieve this exact layout.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since the header extends to the end of the right column, paracol should be perfect for this.  Extending the \colseprule all the way to the \headrule might be tricky.   It might be easier to add your own rules using `\AddToHooks{shipout/background}` You would have to turn line numbering on and off when you switch columns (I have done that before).

Answer (score 2):

The `memoir` class (a superset of `book`) provides a `\sidebar{<stuff>}` macro which puts `<stuff>` into the margin, starting at the top of the page and can continue for several pages. You can control which margin is used.

To me, the question of the vertical rule is a separate one.

On the other hand there are packages which cater for parallel versions of a document (say one in Ancient Greek and the corresponding European translation) but off hand I can't remember them.